# Custom hovers using plotly.js with react

Tags: reactjs, plotly

Looking for the best way of implementing a custom hover with plotly.js along with react.  The following is in the plotly.js docs https://plot.ly/javascript/hover-events/

```
var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
    hoverInfo = document.getElementById('hoverinfo'),
    d3 = Plotly.d3,
    N = 16,
    x = d3.range(N),
    y1 = d3.range(N).map( d3.random.normal() ),
    y2 = d3.range(N).map( d3.random.normal() ),
    data = [ { x:x, y:y1, type:'scatter', name:'Trial 1',
        mode:'markers', marker:{size:16} },
        { x:x, y:y2, type:'scatter', name:'Trial 2',
        mode:'markers', marker:{size:16} } ];
    layout = {
        hovermode:'closest',
        title:'Hover on Points'
     };

Plotly.plot('myDiv', data, layout);

myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function(data){
    var infotext = data.points.map(function(d){
      return (d.data.name+': x= '+d.x+', y= '+d.y.toPrecision(3));
    });

    hoverInfo.innerHTML = infotext.join('
');
})
 .on('plotly_unhover', function(data){
    hoverInfo.innerHTML = '';
});
```

But when using react I'm not sure how to get a reference to the #hoverInfo div.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ref`

```
render() {
  <div id='hoverInfo' ref={ (el) => this.hoverInfo = el }>
  </div>
}
```

will give you a reference in your component to the hoverInfo div which can be used with a library like plotly.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem and found the easiest way to customize hovers is using the `hovertempleate` property, if you only want to customized the text: https://plotly.com/javascript/hover-text-and-formatting/

Another option is playing with `onHover` and `onUnhover` props in the layout: https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/ You can define an state `hover` which turns true when hovered and false when unhovered. With hover true you could make your component to appear with the information you need.